Find events with end date + 3 days
I have a table with events with start and end dates. I need to select the events that have passed, but only if 3 days have passed since the end date.
My current query is:
WHERE end_date < CURDATE() ORDER BY date DESC
I need it to be something like:
WHERE end_date + 3 days < CURDATE() ORDER BY date DESC
What would be the correct syntax?

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp

You need DATE_ADD:
WHERE DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 3 DAY) < CURDATE() ORDER BY date DESC

